# Creating Files in windows 8 metro

Tags: xml, windows, c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was searching to create xml files in windows 8 metro apps using c#, any link I came across is how to manipulate xml, I could'nt find any thing on how to create a .xml file that will be stored on the harddisk.

I want something like this in metro apps, but Windows.xml doest not provide this.

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("output.xml", null);
```

What exactly I wanted to ask was to check if file exist when application starts, adn if doesnot exist the handled exception will create a file with xml documentElement.
How do I do this?

Comment: MSDN has plenty of references about creating files. Keep in mind that Windows Store Apps must declare folders that they need access to so that users can say "yes" or "no" to the permission request. Additionally, you will need to learn about asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 0):

Modern UI apps runs in sand box environment. You donot have direct access to file system.

File IO API is completely revamped (and async).

You can get filestream using Pickers. [Example](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-metro-app-tip-day)

Alternatively you can use App data folders to create files. [App data access quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)

[Reading and writing a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This code example shows how to write XML to a file in a Windows Store 8 App using C#. It also includes code for checking if the file exists. Good luck!

[XLinq, XmlReader, and XmlWriter data message query sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XLinq-XmlReader-and-1e17c0a5)